# Which packages should I install to make Fedora 21 connect to internet by Android Phone?

Tags: ubuntu, fedora, android

In the past I used Ubuntu 14.04 and when I want to connect to internet by my Android phone, I connect it directly using USB cable without installing drivers or some packages like using the Huawei Mobile Broadband, and in Fedora 21 when I connect my Android phone to connect to internet, it is not working like in Ubuntu

Is there drivers or some packages to install to make Fedora 21 workstation x64 to connect to the internet by Android phone?

Comment: Have you tried this guide? http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/17/html/System_Administrators_Guide/sec-Establishing_a_Mobile_Broadband_Connection.html